# Symfony - Infinite loop [302]

Tags: php, symfony

I trying to do redirect from /login if user is logged in from this tutorial: https://codereviewvideos.com/course/getting-started-with-fosuserbundle/video/ux-improvements-part-1-redirect-login-when-logged-in
but now I getting infinite loop with code 302, here is my code:

```
<?php
// src/crmBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php
namespace crmBundle\Controller;


use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        if ($user instanceof User) {

            return new RedirectResponse(
                $this->generateUrl('dashboard')
            );

        }

        return parent::loginAction($request);
    }
}
```

.

```
// src/crmBundle/crmBundle.php
namespace crmBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class crmBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }

}
```

.

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

**Problem resolved.**

Comment: As you seem to have solved the problem, would you mind letting us know what the fix was?